# "The operation couldn’t be completed. (BKAgentServiceErrorDomain error 8.)"

Tags: books, high-sierra

I recently updated to High Sierra, and am now unable to open books (ePubs/PDFs alike) via iBooks. These books are *there*, I can drag them out to my Desktop or sync them to my iPad, but they do not open in iBooks.

Instead, an alert is displayed with the following text:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (BKAgentServiceErrorDomain error 8.)
```

A black-HUD-ed spinner appears on the book's icon, spinning indefinitely.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue, and not sure how to solve it.
I refreshed and stopped indexing:
sudo mdutil -i off /
sudo mdutil -E / Logged out, deauthorised the machine, then logged in and reauthorised:
Still same error!
This happened since updating to High Sierra. Books are still accessible on iPad

Comment: There was a recent update to the iBooks app. Did you update?

Comment: None of my epubs can be opened since high sierra upgrade. The solutions above did not work for me. I hope Apple will remember that iBooks is Apple software, so the issue is clearly with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is crazy, but it worked (after *everything else* failed). I opened:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Updates
```

And clicked on the ePub/PDF files there. iBooks **opened them**. In my case, I had 1 ePub file, and 1 PDF file. I don't know how or why, but I can confirm that it is an issue related to the `Updates` folder, because simply deleting that folder caused the problem to resurface.

To all those out there - good luck dealing with this infuriating app.